# \text not works in "cases" blocks

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, texmaker

I would like to define a multi-rule function with conditions that contain some text terms. For example i want to mention if "the couples are next to each other" the function is equal to something. I try a code like below:

```
    \[ I(x_i) = 
    \begin{cases} 
    1    & \quad \text{if i'th ‎couple ‎sit ‎next ‎to ‎each ‎other‎} \\ 
    0    & \quad \text{O.W. } \\ 
    \end{cases} ‎
    \]
```

but this is my pdf view:

[image]

what's wrong?

I should mention that i have imported `\usepackage{amsmath}` into code and i program in bidiTexmaker2016.

*Added after editing:*

It is important to say i use a particular style package (mean that a particular .sty file)that constructed for writing article in Persian language. But i'd like to write the rule condition in English. After i posted this question, i try with texts in Persian words, and the result was OK:

[image]

So, i think i have to change my question title to "How can i write a text in English in a non-English context".

Comment: looks like it is trying to find latin letters in the RTL font

Answer (score 2):

`\mbox` instead of `\text` seems to work (disclaimer: I am not familiar with package `bidi`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin{document}
  \[ I(x_i) = 
    \begin{cases} 
    1    & \quad \mbox{if $i$'th couple sit next to each other} \\
    0    & \quad \mbox{\setLTR O.W.} \\ 
    \end{cases} <200E>
    \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

From the documentation of `bidi`, `\LR` can be used for short texts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin{document}
  \[ I(x_i) = 
    \begin{cases} 
    1    & \quad \text{\LR{if $i$'th couple sit next to each other}} \\
    0    & \quad \text{\LR{O.W.}} \\ 
    \end{cases} <200E>
    \]
\end{document}
```

The examples were tested with XeLaTeX.

Version with package `polyglossia`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{farsi}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily{\arabicfont}{FreeSerif.otf}
\begin{document}
  \[ I(x_i) =
    \begin{cases}
    1    & \text{\textenglish{if $i$'th couple sit next to each other}} \\
    0    & \text{\textenglish{O.W.}} \\
    \end{cases}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks! but unfortunately  nether "\mbox" works nor "\LR!". Just when i wrote second one, appeared a "i" at condition place...because the "i" was between $$; and when is copy my condition text between dollars, print it without any space between the characters. like this: ifi′thcouplesitnexttoeachother!

Comment: @Shahab_HK Math mode for text is not the best solution. Can you extend the snippet in the question to a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that the problem can be reproduced by others (best, if there are no special installation requirements (fonts, ...) and a standard TeX Live or MiKTeX suffices)?

Comment: ok; i will edit my question and extend it.